# psql drop all tables timeout on Travis Cypress

Tags: travis-ci, psql, cypress

I'm using Travis to run Cypress tests.  I need to refresh the database between tests.  I have Cypress set to `cy.exec` this psql script between tests:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM pg_locks) AND query NOT LIKE '%pg_stat_activity%';
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public;
```

The problem is that it somehow times out randomly when trying to do this.  Seems to run fine when testing locally though.  This also times out randomly on Semaphore CI and CircleCI.

Edit: New development using CircleCI.  I can now see the error:

```
LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
FATAL:  connection to client lost
```

Comment: Would be great, if you could share some relevant logs.

Comment: Sadly the log is not very detailed/informative.  This is literally all it says:

`CypressError: cy.exec('psql -h localhost -c 'drop schema if exists public cascade' webservice_test) timed out after waiting 60000ms.`

Comment: Does the connection `localhost` still holds right while running in Travis?

Comment: Yes, localhost works fine on Travis.  Most of these tests run fine and is able to use the database.  It just sometimes times out randomly.